# Is it ever correct to say 'I wish I was'...something?

Tags: grammar, phrases, sentence

I think it is grammatically not correct to use the phrase 'I wish I was' in any sentence or, any situation. The correct phrase for its substitute will be 'I wish I were'. For instance, *I wish I were on the first floor* (I am actually staying on the ground floor).

Comment: In most situations, you can use "was" instead of irrealis "were" (sometimes wrongly called the 'past subjunctive').

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since 'I wish I was' explicitly is referring to a hypothetical situation, it's invoking what's called [Subjunctive Mood](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/english-subjunctive-what-is-it/).

> The subjunctive mood is a verb form that is used for unreal or hypothetical statements. It is made up of the phrases I were, he were, she were, it were, etc. You often use this form when you are being wishful. For example,
>
> - I wish I weren’t so shy.
> - I wish it were warmer outside.
>
> <sup>[Was vs. Were: What’s the Difference?](https://writingexplained.org/was-vs-were-difference)</sup>

So, if you're concerned with grammatical correctness then it should always be "I wish I were..." (unless you can devise a sentence where "I wish..." isn't referring to a hypothetical situation). In the real world, those less concerned with grammar will use "I wish I was..." and everyone will still understand what they mean.

Comment: So is it ever correct to say "I wish I was"? Your explanation skips over what seems to be the main part of the original question.

Comment: Huddlestone et al say that the indicative must be considered accepted here nowadays. And this is a multi-dupe.